# Change TextView color when SeekBar passes through value

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I have 7 `TextViews` and one `SeekBar`

[image]

I have the following code which is supposed to change the text color as I move the thumb in the `SeekBar`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    SeekBar sbOne, sbTwo;
    SeekBar sbSyst;
    TextView tvOne;
    TextView tvSOne, tvSTwo, tvSThree, tvSFour, tvSFive, tvSSix, tvSSeven;
    NumberPicker npO, npT;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sbSyst = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.syst_bar);
        sbSyst.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        sbOne = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb1);
        sbOne.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        sbTwo = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb2);
        sbTwo.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        tvOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        tvSOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFirst);
        tvSTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSecond);
        tvSThree = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvThird);
        tvSFour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFourth);
        tvSFive = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFifth);
        tvSSix = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSixth);
        tvSSeven = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSeventh);

        /*npO = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np1);
        npO.setMinValue(70);
        npO.setMaxValue(190);
        npO.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        npO.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                // do something here
                tvOne.setText(String.valueOf(newVal));
            }
        });

        npT = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np2);
        npT.setMinValue(40);
        npT.setMaxValue(100);
        npT.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);*/

    }

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

        //tvSColor.setBackgroundColor(getColorFromSeekbars());

    progress += 70;

        switch(seekBar.getId()) {
        case R.id.sb1:
            //etO.setText(String.valueOf(progress+70));
            //npO.setValue(progress+70);
            break;
        case R.id.sb2:
            //etT.setText(String.valueOf(progress+40));
            //npT.setValue(progress+40);
            break;
        case R.id.syst_bar:
            tvOne.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            if (progress == 70) {
                tvSOne.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));
                tvSTwo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSThree.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSFour.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSFive.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSSix.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSSeven.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else if (progress == 90) {
                tvSOne.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSTwo.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));
                tvSThree.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSFour.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSFive.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSSix.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSSeven.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else if (progress == 110) {
                tvSOne.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSTwo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSThree.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));
                tvSFour.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSFive.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSSix.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSSeven.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else if (progress == 130) {
                tvSOne.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSTwo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSThree.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSFour.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));
                tvSFive.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSSix.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSSeven.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else if (progress == 150) {
                tvSOne.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSTwo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSThree.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSFour.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSFive.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));
                tvSSix.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSSeven.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else if (progress == 170) {
                tvSOne.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSTwo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSThree.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSFour.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSFive.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSSix.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));
                tvSSeven.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else if (progress == 190) {
                tvSOne.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSTwo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSThree.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSFour.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSFive.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSSix.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvSSeven.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));
            }
            //etT.setText(String.valueOf(progress+70));
            //npT.setValue(progress+40);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        //mTrackingText.setText("Tracking on");
    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        //tvOne.setText("Red: " + String.valueOf(progress));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh_match_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_round"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Systolic (top number)"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/syst_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:progress="0"
        android:max="190"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
        android:secondaryProgress="0"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_state" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="14" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFirst"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="70"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSecond"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="90"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvThird"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="110"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFourth"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="130"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFifth"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="150"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSixth"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="170"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSeventh"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="190"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am probably not doing it correctly, but as you can see the value of `progress` is 190 from the image but the third `TextView` is green and not the last. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: did it pass from 70 to 90 to finaly 110 ?

Comment: I want it to change the color consequently as I move the thumb in the `SeekBar`. Do I have to use `while` statement?

Comment: can you post the implementation of your seekbar

Comment: Which implementation? XML?

Comment: there you go, in the xml, you have android:max="120", make it android:max="190"

Comment: Change it back to == now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should probably change `==` to `>=`

updated answer:

in the xml, you have `android:max="120"`, make it `android:max="190"`

Comment: Once I leave the 70 mark, I want it to turn white. Same goes for the rest of the values. Only 70 is now highlighted green and no matter where I move it stays green.

Comment: I should change the >= to ==?

Comment: yes , the >= is valid if you want the 70 to be active untill you pass through 90, but if you need it to be active ONLY on 70, then change it back to ==

Comment: SeekBar always starts from 0 but I want it to start from 70 so I updated my question with this line `progress += 70` but it seems ONLY 70 is highlighted no matter where the thumb is.

Comment: change it to progress += 70;, notice the +=, in your java there is =+, this makes it always 70

Comment: It's not working correctly :/!!! I changed and now it sometime works and sometime when the thumb is at 110, 150 is highlighted and so forth... any idea why it's giving the issue?

Comment: I updated my code and when the thumb is at 190, `tvOne` is showing 260 instead of 190 :/ I think that's where the issue is... When the thumb is over 110, it works fine the first time and then when going back to 70, and I slide the thumb to higher number, that's when it seems to mess up.

Comment: hold on, this is it, set the max value in the xml to 190-70 wich is 120, (wich is the original value) now with the modifications, it should work

Comment: not weird at all, think about it, you each time add 70, because it starts at 0 not 70, so the max value should be yourMAxValue - 70, to stay balanced

Comment: Wow... you are right. Keeping it at 120 worked!!! weird!!! What is happening now, if I slide the thumb too fast and 190 was highlighted but the thumb is now at 90, 190 stays highlighted :/ Guess it's not keeping up fast enough? Any idea how to make it update no matter how slow or fast the thumb is moved?

Comment: well that one is weird, add a Log.i(..) and check the progress value, do some debugging

Comment: I added a `TextView to see the progress and it's showing the correct value but the number is not highlighted.

Comment: try this. put all the code of the case "syst_bar" inside a handler. Handler handler = new handler(); handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ run(){YOUR CODE}}, 100);

Comment: I am trying to do what you said, the app is throwing an error. Can you please post example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43979/discussion-between-user2427819-and-sikni8)

Comment: OK... No one is there. Its almost 5AM here... I will sign into chat later on today to discuss the code?

Answer (score 1):

In the above code you have used **else if** so what happens is that when the first **if** or any of the **else if** becomes true then rest of the **else if** below that are not evaluated.Hence you get the same color.  Try using **if** in all the conditional statements and you will get the desired result.I tested it :)

EDIT: Adding codes to make it more clear

MainActivity.java

```
package com.abc.def;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

SeekBar sb;
TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // set the message to display
        alertbox.setMessage("Wanna go to www.moma.org for more info?");

        // add a neutral button to the alert box and assign a click listener
        alertbox.setNegativeButton("NOPE!!",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    // click listener on the alert box
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // the button was clicked

                    }
                });

        alertbox.setPositiveButton("YEAH!!",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    // click listener on the alert box
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // the button was clicked
                        String url = "http://www.moma.org";

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });

        // show it
        alertbox.show();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromTouch) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (seekBar.getId()) {
    case R.id.seekBar1:
        // tvOne.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        if (progress >= 10) {
            tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));
            tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv5.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        }if (progress >= 20) {
            tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));
            tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv5.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        }if (progress >= 40) {
            tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));
            tv4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv5.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        }if (progress >= 60) {
            tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));
            tv5.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        }if (progress >= 70) {
            tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));

        }if (progress >= 80) {
            tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            tv5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00996a"));

        }if (progress >= 100) {
            tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv5.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        }

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/verti"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/beach1"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:weightSum="100"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200sp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="158dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFEE66"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#AABB66"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ee1166"
        android:text="" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0" 
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is late but you do have a point. Thanks. I will test it out.